# how to get the size of subtree of each node?

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I have a tree and i want to find the subtrees at each node. I tried the following code
for reading

```
             scanf("%d %d", &n,&e);
             memset(chk, 0, sizeof sub);
            for(int i = 0; i < e; i++){
                int u, v;
                scanf("%d %d", &u, &v);
                adj[u].push_back(v);
            //adj[v].push_back(u);
            }
```

and the size of the subtree is calculated as

```
int * dfs(int current, int parent)
{

        sub[current] = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<adj[current].size();i++)

        {

                int next = adj[current][i];

                if(next == parent)continue;

                dfs(next, current);

                sub[current] += sub[next] + 1;

        }

        return sub;

}
```

I defined adj as
adj[u].push_back(v);
test case where this algorithm failed
Input file:

```
9 7
0 1
1 2
1 3
2 3
3 4
6 7
6 8
```

i'm getting output as

```
*(s + 0) : 6
*(s + 1) : 5
*(s + 2) : 2
*(s + 3) : 1
*(s + 4) : 0
*(s + 5) : 0
*(s + 6) : 0
*(s + 7) : 0
*(s + 8) : 0
```

working one:input

```
5 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
3 4
output is
*(s + 0) : 0
*(s + 1) : 4
*(s + 2) : 0
*(s + 3) : 1
*(s + 4) : 0
```

Comment: An example would be more helpful.

Comment: added..do you want the full code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You almost never want to provide the full code. You want to provide a minimal but complete subset of the code (a [mcve]) that reproduces the error. Complete is a must. In this case, for example, we don't know if the cause of the counting error is an insertion error. Full code is complete, but almost always isn't minimal. The benefits of presenting a minimal and complete case are smaller surface area that must be debugged and often reducing the code makes the error brutally obvious.

Comment: added reading portion

Comment: So this is data represents a disjoint graph?? Not a tree?? No path from root of tree to all nodes??

Comment: Another hint: when debugging, don't read in user input. Find a set of inputs that triggers the misbehaviour and code it in so that you are always testing the same input. You should be able to build a simple program that is a `main` that always adds the same nodes and counts via `dfs`, a function that adds the nodes, and `dfs`. If this reproduces the problem, then step through the code with [the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that came with your development environment and look for where the program goes off the rails. If it doesn't reproduce the problem, the bug is elsewhere